# download in async httpclient xml file

Tags: xamarin

I want to download an xml file in asynchronous and let the user know that the file is downloading while it does other moves in the app

```cs
public static async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{            
   using (var httpClient = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue })
   {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   }
}
```

with this command did not work successfully

Comment: what do you mean by "did not work"?  Did it give you an error or exception?  Did it not behave as intended.  You need to be more specific about the problem if you expect us to help you.

Comment: it does not generate errors, async does not happen

Comment: "async does not happen" what does this mean? How do you call `GetRequestAsync`?